# Mongoose: how to pull from array in document instance

Tags: mongoose

Lets say I have the following schema in Mongoose:

```
var OrganisationSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name:       { type: String },
  users:      [ UserSchema ]
});

var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name:       { type: String, required: true },
  email:      { type: String, required: true }
});
```

And I saw this example in the [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html) of mongoose

```
doc.array.pull(ObjectId)
doc.array.pull({ _id: 'someId' })
doc.array.pull(36)
doc.array.pull('tag 1', 'tag 2')
```

Therefore I wonder why this function does not work:

```
OrgSchema.methods.removeUser = function(mail, onRemoveError, onRemoveSucess) {
  var org = this;
  org.users.pull({email: mail});
  org.save(function(err) {
    if(err) {
      onRemoveError(err);
    } else {
      onRemoveSuccess(org); // Gets called but has not removed the user
    }  
  });
};
```

This kind of `pull` does not work and I wonder why? Most of the question threads here on stackoverflow refer to the mongodb pull method for doing this sort of thing:

```
Org.update( { _id: orgid }, { $pull: { candidates: { email: mail }}});
```

Is this the correct way to go? Can´t I pull directly on a document array?

Comment: I believe you are on the right track. Implementing a method at the document level makes this very efficient.

Comment: @ZeMoon I edited my question after trying this implementation.

Comment: Log `org.users` just after `org.users.pull()`. Is your change taking place?

Comment: Solved it by using `org.candidates.pull(id)`. I could use id instead but not the query: `{email: mail}`

Comment: Okay. The mongoose method only expects an id. If you want to base it on a query, you will have to use update instead.

Comment: Please add an answer. It might help other people who face the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by using the `org.candidates.pull(id)` as specified in the documentation. Query parameters did not seem to work.